# Technique to find pages from a link

Tags: php, .net, algorithm, seo

I have planned to write a great SEO tool and I want to know how can I find pages from a static/dynamic website link.

I will just have domain like www.yahoo.com and my system should find all pages that exists in that host.

Are there any techniques to do that? I can use any language but I think .NET will really boost things up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would almost certainly have to parse the page code for references to HREF=

You could request the URL using `System.WebRequest.Create(uri)` and then Regex over the response stream.

I would certainly be interested if there was an easier way in .Net.

Comment: I know this way but won't that left some pages which has no link on any page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just "magically" find all pages that exist on the domain, unless there is a sitemap (which won't exist most of the time).

Here is what you can do
1. Brute force - This is a bad idea as it will just take a very very long time.
2. Regex over source code - Look for regular expressions within  tags

2 is your best bet, as it will provide all links on that page. I would consider adding a recursive functionality so that you "spider" out and perform the same regex operation on all pages found in the seed.

Here is the algorithm

> 1. Start with a seed (ie: www.yahoo.com)
> 2. Perform regex on the source code of this page, and store all links in a
>      data structure
> 3. Recursively call #1 on each link found in #2. You might want to
>      restrict this to only links that live
>      on the seed domain (ie: start with or
>      contain www.yahoo.com), as well as excluding links to pages that you've already visited

A tree datastructure with a visitor design pattern would be ideal for this type of implementation.